# VB6 starting with Microsoft Professional Studio Professional 2012 initialization window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vb6

For some reason, once and again I start VB6, and the window "Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012" pops up.

This is a screenshot:

[image]

I guess something was changed and either VB6 or VS2012 struggles to find it again.
Am I right?

I used ProcMon to determine which files are trying to be accessed, but it did not spit out anything.

This window is highly annoying. It takes around 3 minutes to be unloaded. 
At the next start of VB6, it pops up again.

I can cancel it, but having to do that is also really annoying. Also I would like to find out what causes this behaviour.

Can anybody help?

ps: Sometimes when I click "Cancel", I get the following message:

[image]

ps: At least I have found out that the process is MSIEXEC.EXE that does this...

Comment: Have you recently installed any new software or updates? It is possible that the install didn't quite work, and needs to be "repaired". I used to have this problem with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a Windows Installer shortcut being used to start Windows (you can tell in the shortcut's property if you can't edit it). Make a normal shortcut to vb6.exe.

Try this selecting VS2012 (this is Vista but other versions have similar)

Fixit

Microsoft have a range of automatic programs to fix common problems. For Windows Installer problems see

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/en-us

For the full list visit

http://support.microsoft.com/fixit/en-us

When you choose to download it, choose the option to run on another computer. Then you can save it to your harddisk in a folder. Open the folder, open the folder Fix it Portable, and run Launch Fix It. It will contain all 27 Fixits.

How To Use Fixit

Start Fix problems that programs cannot be installed or uninstalled.

Next you'll be asked Install or Uninstall.

If Installing and you have previously installed or attempted to install try uninstalling first.

Next you will get a list. Choose from that list.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work, but thank you. Link to VB6 is a usual "C:\Program Files (x86)\VS\VB98\VB6.EXE"